# React Native - How to parse json data and set it in a state object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I have two files (in the same directory):

- Detail.json
- Base.js

**Detail.json** is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "B",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "C",
  }
];
```

**Base.js** is as follows:

```
class Base extends Component {

state = { myDetail: [] }; 

//TODO 1: fetch JSON data from Detail.json and set it to myDetail object

//TODO 2: parse this data from myDetail to display as a single unit (eg: name)

}
```

I did:

```
import data from './Detail.json'
```

`console.log(data)` gives me my full json object. But when I do:

```
this.setState({myDetail: data});
```

& then `console.log(myDetail);` it shows empty object in console.

Can someone please tell me how to perform the above two tasks. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where, specifically, did you run into trouble?

Comment: @smarx I did: import data from './Detail.json'

console.log(data) - this gives me my full json object.

but

when I do: this.setState({myDetail: data});

& then console.log(myDetail);

It shows empty object in console.

Comment: @alex I've updated the JSON format. This is the one I'm using. Can you suggest now. Thanks.

Comment: Do you just need `console.log(this.state.myDetail);`?

Comment: @smarx yes. Still the same. empty.

Comment: So simplify the problem. `this.setState({foo: 'bar'}); console.log(this.state.foo);` is apparently not working for you. You can delete the stuff in your question about the JSON file and instead add the code you're using to set and retrieve state.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate
setState is a async function, so please ensure you check the state in next tick, not right in the next line

Answer (score 1):

As told by Yozi in the comments section, `setState` is an async function, you must wait for its promise to get resolved.

```
this.setState({foo: 'bar'}).then(() => {
  console.log(this.state.foo)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s just because your last code `console.log` is called before the state object is updated by `setState` method. But `setState` take a second parameter which is a callback called after the state is updated.

```
this.setState({
     myDetails: data
}, () => {
     console.log(this.state.myDetails);
});
```